# Adding an info label to my image

Tags: html, image

Im not entirely sure what this is actually called which is probably why I havent been able to find help elsewhere.

Basically when I hover my mouse over my image I want it to tell me what it is, for example tell me that, the image is the delete button.

```
"<td><a href=$del><img src=\"del.png\"></td>";
```

This is working fine no issues with what I want it to do. Just want a bit of info about what its doing when mouse is over the image?

Thanks

Comment: Simplest way is to just add title to your img tag. I don't see why php is tagget here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "title" attribute, example:

```
"<td><a href=$del><img src=\"del.png\" title='EXPLANATION HERE'></td>";
```

In this case the text "EXPLANATION HERE" will appear when the mouse is over the image.

Comment: @Mccarthy19, good the hear that. If you want, you may click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: unable to at the moment, but as soon as 3 minutes is up I will do